# Why when I am using "def" function to find prime number the result is "NONE"

Tags: python

```
def is_prime(number):
    if number>1:
        for factor in range (2,number):
            if number%factor ==0:
                return False
            else:
                return True

def get_primes(n):
        for number in range (1,n):
            if is_prime(number):
                print('%d is prime' %number)
print (get_primes(3))
```

When i use the above code to get the prime number, Why I got "None"?

```
def is_prime(number):
    if number <= 1:
        return False
    
    for factor in range(2, number):
        if number % factor == 0:
            return False

    return True

def print_primes(n):
    for number in range(1, n):
        if is_prime(number):
            print('%d is prime' % number)
```

And this is the correct code from the answer, can anyone help on explaining why my code is wrong. Thanks

Comment: You may want to return something from `get_primes`.

Comment: bcoz your function nothing received in return.....
try to call a function instead of printing

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, what you need to avoid is the double print.

> print(print()) which returns None in python.

Your function is already printing to the console no need to print again.

I took out the print statement,  also your code is not exhaustive enough, 2 and 3 are prime numbers but your function will miss them, and the last number(the argument passed) if it is prime too. added a few lines
the code below should work fine in all cases.

```
def is_prime(number):
    if number>1:
        if number==2 or number==3:
          return True
        for factor in range(2,number):
            if number%factor ==0:
                return False
            else:
                return True

def get_primes(n):
        for number in range (1,n+1):
            if is_prime(number):
                print('%d is prime' %number)
get_primes(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

what the issue is you are printing a function but, function nothing received in return , so function printing a None

```
def is_prime(number):
        if number>1:
            for factor in range (2,number):
                if number%factor ==0:
                    return False
                else:
                    return True
    
def get_primes(n):
        for number in range (1,n):
            if is_prime(number):
                print('%d is prime' %number)
get_primes(3)
```